# Kotlin Serialization @SerialName not working for Boolean

Tags: android, kotlin, serialization, gson

I'm using GSON to serialize some platform data. When I use `@SerialName` to capture platform data with a different naming convention in my app, it works for other types, but not `Boolean` types. As a simple example, if I have a class like...

```kotlin
import kotlinx.serialization.SerialName
import kotlinx.serialization.Serializable

@Serializable
data class Person (
    @SerialName("first_name") val firstName: String? = null,
    @SerialName("last_name") val lastName: String? = null,
    val age: Int? = null
)
```

... everything works fine. The serializer finds `first_name`, `last_name` and `age` in the data and properly set the properties for the `Person`.

However, when I try to add a `Boolean`...

```kotlin
import kotlinx.serialization.SerialName
import kotlinx.serialization.Serializable

@Serializable
data class Person (
    @SerialName("first_name") val firstName: String? = null,
    @SerialName("last_name") val lastName: String? = null,
    val age: Int? = null,
    @SerialName("can_sing") val canSing: Boolean? = null
)
```

... the serializer does not catch and assign `can_sing`. It is strange that it works with a `String` but not a `Boolean`. Can any explain why I am seeing this behavior? I can work around this (for example, I can do `val can_sing: Boolean? = null` and it works), but I'm just wonder why `@SerialName` doesn't seem to work for a `Boolean`, or if I'm just missing something obvious.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are mixing the Gson and Kotlin annotation types - Gson uses `@SerializedName` not `@SerialName`. I am not sure how your string types even work in that case (maybe something in how you call Gson that isn't included in the question).

As an example, the first class here (`Person`) can be serialized with the Kotlin serialization library, the second with Gson:

*Kotlin annotations*

```kotlin
@Serializable
data class Person (
    @SerialName("first_name") val firstName: String? = null,
    @SerialName("last_name") val lastName: String? = null,
    val age: Int? = null,
    @SerialName("can_sing") val canSing: Boolean? = null
)
```

*Gson Annotations*

```kotlin
data class PersonGson (
    @SerializedName("first_name") val firstName: String? = null,
    @SerializedName("last_name") val lastName: String? = null,
    val age: Int? = null,
    @SerializedName("can_sing") val canSing: Boolean? = null
)
```

**Examples**

Running this unit test with the Kotlin serialization library:

```kotlin
@Test
fun testJsonKotlin()  {
    val test = Person("hello", "world", 42, false)
    val json = Json.encodeToString(test)
    println(json)
    val t2 = Json.decodeFromString<Person>(json)
    println(t2)
}
```

produces the expected output:

```
{"first_name":"hello","last_name":"world","age":42,"can_sing":false}
Person(firstName=hello, lastName=world, age=42, canSing=false)
```

Doing that with Gson

```kotlin
@Test
fun testJsonGsonMixed()  {
    val testp = Person("hello", "world", 42, false)
    val json = Gson().toJson(testp)
    println(json)
    val t2 = Gson().fromJson(json, Person::class.java)
    println(t2)
}
```

technically works, but ignores the serialized name annotations (for all the cases, not just the boolean)

```
{"firstName":"hello","lastName":"world","age":42,"canSing":false}
Person(firstName=hello, lastName=world, age=42, canSing=false)
```

Using the Gson-annotated class with Gson

```
@Test
fun testJsonGson()  {
    val test = PersonGson("hello", "world", 42, false)
    val json = Gson().toJson(test)
    println(json)
    val t2 = Gson().fromJson(json, PersonGson::class.java)
    println(t2)
}
```

gives the correct response again

```
{"first_name":"hello","last_name":"world","age":42,"can_sing":false}
PersonGson(firstName=hello, lastName=world, age=42, canSing=false)
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to need to find some time to test this out.

Comment: Feels silly to have missed this, you are spot on. After looking into it, the reason the Strings were working was because I was using `@SerialName` on objects that I was parsing with kotlinx serialization and not GSON. ‍♂️ 

I'm actually realizing I don't even need GSON in this codebase. It is only being used for this one response. Feels inconsistent.